# how to change Android Studio terminal background color

Tags: android, bash, android-studio

Android Studio is so powerful tool and very convenient to use. I super like its Darcula Theme.
But the problem is all windows changed their background color to black except Terminal.
See screenshot below[image]

I noticed I can change the bash path from here
[image]
So I wonder if I can change the terminal background color to be black.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> Console Colors
```

Select

```
Console > Background
```

on the list.

On the extreme right side, you will find `Background` checkbox.

Edit this. **Restart the IDE**. You are ready to go...

Comment: not really, I alreay changed Console background to be black. See the first screen shot above, as I updated it this time, only Terminal background color is white, others windows background is ok

Comment: Did you restart your IDE ?

Comment: Yes, needed to restart Android Studio.

Comment: @CodeToLife I already mentioned **restart the IDE** in my original answer. You might want to give me **up vote** instead of down vote.

Comment: Oh  yes. Apologizes. I downvoted by mistake. Will correct that.

Comment: I can confirm that whenever changing the default theme in *Appearance & Behavior > Appearance* (e.g. from Default to Darcula, or vice versa) a restart of the IDE is needed to reflect this change in the embedded terminal. The change is immediate in all the other windows (e.g. Android Monitor), but just not in the embedded terminal. This behaviour might cause some confusion.

Comment: You do not need to restart the IDE.  Just change the colors as suggested, open terminal IN android studio and type exit.  Then launch the terminal again within android studio and enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

Just hit the [x] button at the left hand side of the Terminal. This will close the terminal, then launch it again. You will see that the color has changed to Darcula as well.