# How to change the background color around the visual design/layout editor in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, graphical-layout-editor

The background around the [Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-layout.html) in Android Studio is dark grey. I think it used to be white. Anyway, I would like to make it white again, but I can't find the setting. The reason I want to change it is so that I can make nicer looking print screen images to use on StackOverflow or app descriptions.

[image]

Note: I'm not talking about changing the theme or the code editor colors. These questions have already been answered here:

- [How to change or add theme to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579448/how-to-change-or-add-theme-to-android-studio)
- [How do I change Android Studio editor's background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601260/how-do-i-change-android-studio-editors-background-color)
- [how to change Android Studio terminal background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098926/how-to-change-android-studio-terminal-background-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated Answer

Android Studio 3.0 has a Screenshot menu item. Right click the design area and choose **Save Screenshot**.

[image]

From there you can make a screenshot with a transparent background.